# How to add html element as generated content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put html element as generated content. for example if i want to put horizontal line before list item

This doesn't works. it just print '<hr/>' as text

```
li:before{
     content : '<hr/>'
}
```

Is there any way to do it

Comment: *"Is there any way to do it?"* - yes. *"How did you do it?"* - `undefined`.

Comment: so how about the answer? does anybody have 1?

Comment: @fastreload did u just give the usage example or source for the solution? i just don't get it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible to do it with css.

One solution might be to use a `border-top` on your `li` instead.

e.g.

```
li
{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Look at this site for some good examples of what *can* be done: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Answer (score 2):

> HTML code cannot be inserted, using css content property, the tags
>   show up as `<tag>`.

You can use jquery pretty easy..

```
$('li').prepend('<hr />');
```